# magrittr pipe of dot to do.call function

Tags: r, magrittr, do.call

When the `.` is transferred indirectly to the function like `do.call`, then the `magrittr` does not see the `.`.

Example which will gives an error, as dot is not visible.

```r
airquality %>% do.call("mean", list(x = .$Ozone, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there is a dot as an argument to the main function, here `do.call`, the pipe will insert the left hand side into argument 1.  Using dot within an expression does not count.

Brace brackets can be used to disable automatic insertion, `with` can be used such that `with` is the main function instead of `do.call`, use magrittr's `%$%` pipe or use a function which explicitly does what you want.

(Note that `mean` will give a result of NA if there are any NA's in its argument; to suppress the NA's add `na.rm=TRUE` as an argument to mean -- not shown.)

```
airquality %>% { do.call("mean", list(x = .$Ozone)) }

airquality %>% with(do.call("mean", list(x = Ozone)))

library(magrittr)
airquality %$% do.call("mean", list(x = Ozone))

# needs R 4.1+ . With earlier versions use function(.) in place of \(.)
airquality %>% (\(.) do.call("mean", list(x = .$Ozone)))
```

### |>

With the |> pipe introduced into base R 4.1 these work but not the analogs to others above:

```
airquality |> with(do.call("mean", list(x = Ozone)))

airquality |> (\(.) do.call("mean", list(x = .$Ozone)))()
```

Comment: This is a true high quality one.

Comment: Could you edit and add na.rm to all of your examples. I updated the question. thanks

Comment: This is fascinating that people will give you likes for this last comment although not vote for a question or even answer (at least one of them not vote as i voted on your one). This is so funny on stack.

Answer (score 1):

Because `list` is open for unnamed arguments (...), `.` goes to the first argument. This can be expressed as

```
list(., x = .$Ozone)
```

Using `with` solves the problem.

```r
airquality %>% with(., do.call("mean", list(x = Ozone, na.rm = TRUE)))
```